# Laravel Passing Parameter from Route to Controller breaks down page

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass a route variable to the controller and it breaks down the whole page because if I go to network tab, it's being fetched as a document.

Here is the function in the controller:

```
public function watch($id)
{
      //Some logic goes here
}
```

Here is my Route:

```
Route::get('/watch/{id}', "HomeController@watch");
```

and the page looks something like:

```
localhost:8040/mysite/public/watch/1J76wN0TPI4
```

Here is a screenshot of the page after it loads:

[Please check this image](http://prntscr.com/jtiztg)

Comment: why are you going through '/public' path?

Comment: Where is the error or what kinda error you got? What is network tab and document? Please be more specific.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/jtiztg

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin because i am using apache as a server, though i tried setting my document root to public path but it didn't solved the issue

Comment: @AliÖzen please check the screenshot, if remove the ending paramter the page loads fine but with the ending parameter, there's not style or javascript on page

Comment: @AliÖzen please also do note the network tab where browser is searching for page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your assets are being loaded incorrectly.

Assets meaning JS and CSS files, your base template or your main blade file is probably linking directly to a source url, once you add the new url that becomes obsolete.

example

```
mysite.com/mycss.css
```

The above being a css file in your main blade, and a lot of people develop this with a absolute url

when you add the route `watch/id` the file is then reading like this

```
mysite.com/watch/1/mycss.css
```

That is the error

In your blade template, reference all assets using the asset helper
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset